# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed after add `return`

Tags: java, servlets, requestdispatcher

I want to redirect the url after user input name and password, but there are something wrong.
some people say that add `return` after  `forward(request,response)`, and this method doesn't work.

> ```
>     RequestDispatcher dispatcher;
>     String username = request.getParameter("username");
>     String passwd = request.getParameter("passwd");
>     if(username != null && passwd != null){
>         try{
>             Database database = new Database("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
>                     "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/picshow","root","000000");
>             ResultSet rs = database.query("select * from ps_user where name=?", username);
>             if(rs.next()){
>                 if(rs.getString("passwd").equals(passwd)){
>                     HttpSession session = request.getSession();
>                     session.setAttribute("username", username);
>                     System.out.println("login successful");
>                     dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()+"/personalpage.jsp");
>                     dispatcher.forward(request, response);
>                     return;
>                 }else {
>                     errMsg = "invalid password";
>                 }
>             }else {
>                 errMsg="user not exist";
>             }
>         }catch(Exception e){
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>         if(errMsg != null && !errMsg.equals("")){
>             dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()+"/login.jsp");
>             request.setAttribute("errMsg", errMsg);
>             dispatcher.forward(request, response);
>             return;
>         }
>     }else {
>         dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()+"/login.jsp");
>         dispatcher.forward(request, response);
>         return;
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead create a String variable, set your destination based on your condition and finally forward it.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher;
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String passwd = request.getParameter("passwd");
String destination = "";//new targe variable
if(username != null && passwd != null){
    try{
        Database database = new Database("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/picshow","root","000000");
        ResultSet rs = database.query("select * from ps_user where name=?", username);
        if(rs.next()){
            if(rs.getString("passwd").equals(passwd)){
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("username", username);
                System.out.println("login successful");
                destination=request.getContextPath()+"/personalpage.jsp";//set your target
            }else {
                errMsg = "invalid password";
            }
        }else {
            errMsg="user not exist";
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(errMsg != null && !errMsg.equals("")){
        destination=request.getContextPath()+"/login.jsp";//set your target
        request.setAttribute("errMsg", errMsg);
    }
}else {
    destination=request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()+"/login.jsp");//set 
}

dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(destination);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've found the cause of the error. The reason is that I call the `forward` twice(before this piece of code). So this piece of code are correct....